¿Como resolver problemas de importacion en Python "No se ha podido resolver la importación"?
Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con Django y DRF, creer una app para un registro, quiero implementar filtros para los datos, buscando encontre django-filter para poder hacer filtros, instale el paquete en mi env y agregue las configuraciones en mi settings.py
Al momento de hacer mi filters.py y hacer la integracion con DRF como marca su documentacion me muestra un error
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters No se ha podido resolver la importacion "django_filters".

settings.py
 THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'djoser',
    'social_django',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
    'django_filters'
]

INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + PROJECT_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': [
        'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend'
    ],
}

la configuracion esta como en la documentacion de django-filter y las versiones utilizadas en el proyecto son compatibles entre si, ya elimine mi env, elimine cache de pip y volvi a crearlo, el interprete es el adecuado
filters.py
from .models import *
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters

class AgencyFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    country = filters.CharFilter(field_name='country')
    state = filters.CharFilter(field_name='state')
    city = filters.CharFilter(field_name='city')

    class Meta:
        model = Agency
        fields = ['country', 'state', 'city']


Hola, solo por acotar el problema ¿Si ejecutas el proyecto tienes una excepción ModuleNotFoundError a causa de éste módulo? ¿Si intentas importarlo desde el intérpete interactivo en una terminal, con el VENV previamente activado en ella, te genera un error? Lo digo porque eso no es un error del intéprete, es un aviso del  analizador de código de turno ¿Pylance?, normalmente eso se traduce en un error de importacion al ejecutar pero hay casos donde es solo un problema de la herramienta de analisis o configuración del IDE y no un error real.

Tienes toda la razón, es un problema de la herramienta de analisis, ya que al correr el proyecto no me da la excepción ModuleNotFoundError.
De ante mano te agradezco el que ta hayas omado el tiempo de comentar
